# Elasticbeanstalk How do I specify Pango >= 1.38 in my config files?

Tags: elastic-beanstalk

I'm getting the following error:

> Elasticbeanstalk UserWarning: @font-face support needs Pango >= 1.38

I need to install Pango >= 1.38 on elasticbeanstalk.

I have the following `.ebextensions\01_packages.config` file

```
packages:
  yum:
    git: []
    postgresql93-devel: []
    libxslt-devel: []
    libxml2-devel: []
    python36: []
    gcc-c++: []
    gcc-gfortran: []
    atlas-sse3-devel: []
    lapack-devel: []
    libffi: []
    libffi-devel: []
    cairo-devel: []
    pango: []
    pango-devel : []
```

This is loading pango 1.28 as per this extract from the eb-activity.log

```
> ---> Package pango.x86_64 0:1.28.1-10.11.amzn1 will be installed   --> Processing Dependency: libthai >= 0.1.9 for package:
> pango-1.28.1-10.11.amzn1.x86_64   --> Processing Dependency:
> libthai.so.0(LIBTHAI_0.1)(64bit) for package:
> pango-1.28.1-10.11.amzn1.x86_64   --> Processing Dependency:
> libthai.so.0()(64bit) for package: pango-1.28.1-10.11.amzn1.x86_64  
> --> Processing Dependency: libXft.so.2()(64bit) for package: pango-1.28.1-10.11.amzn1.x86_64   ---> Package pango-devel.x86_64
> 0:1.28.1-10.11.amzn1 will be installed   --> Processing Dependency:
> pkgconfig(xft) for package: pango-devel-1.28.1-10.11.amzn1.x86_64  
> --> Processing Dependency: libXft-devel for package: pango-devel-1.28.1-10.11.amzn1.x86_64
```

I've tried amending to

```
...
    pango: 1.44.0
    pango-devel : 1.44.0
```

Which gives the following error on installation:

> Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: Yum does not have
>   pango-1.44.0 available for installation.

I do I get a more recent version of Pango installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally upgraded to latest version of Elastic Beanstalk which was the only way I could resolve this